# 400 response: service unavailable (am i doing a a sell wrong or is it coinbase?)

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I'm trying to get a quote for a small amount of bitcoin and it's been giving me back a 400 response back with the error saying the service is unavailable`{'errors': [{'id': 'service_unavailable', 'message': 'It looks like we encountered a problem. Sorry for the trouble!'}]}`

The following code is what is what i'm using and I have the (wallet:buys:create) buy scope on as well

```
    def sell(self):

    link="https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/"+self.id+"/sells"

    data = {
    'amount': '.001',
    'currency': "BTC",
    'payment_method': self.method[1][1],#id of the payment method
    "quote":"true"
}
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.tokens[0]}'                      
}
    r = requests.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(r.json())
```

Comment: Looks like their server is a broken as their return code. (should be 503).

Answer (score 0):

400 is `bad request`, they do have it labeled wrong like @klausd suggested.

That said, the docs for sells shows the request type is get and you're using post which would be a bad request.

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#list-sells

> GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/:account_id/sells

Comment: I'm trying to do a sell with my code so it has to be a post. The code you're showing would get me a list of sells the account did

Comment: @2DNinja ah sorry. i mostly use the pro api and not overly familiar with the coinbase stuff. That said, the python examples in the documentation use their own coinbase client. but looking at the shell example the url has a trailing `/`.  have you tried `https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/"+self.id+"/sells/` to see if that works?